# How to play amr file (BLOB) from DB with VueJS and .NET?

Tags: .net, audio, vuejs2, html5-audio, amr

I have some MP3 and amr files converted into Base64. I converted my audio files on this page:
https://base64.guru/converter/encode/audio

I installed an npm library, I show that it can play mp3 blob but amr file not.

What should I do, which npm library I should download to play my each mp3 and amr files?
Also, When I write File(resultDto.MediaContent, "audio/mp3"), can .NET cast and return my amr file to mp3?

I am sending request from client side. Fetching BLOB data on server and returning as `return File(resultDto.MediaContent, "audio/mp3");` (It returns base64 string)

On the client side I am adding "data:audio/mp3;base64, " in front of the result. It can play my mp3 file but can't amr.
If I change my .NET code and Vue2 code as "amr", player can't play both of them. So, I thought that the problem is on the player library which I downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I installed ffmpeg on my PC. I wrote a bash script that takes the folder path and converts all .amr files into .mp3.
Then, I converted mp3 files into .txt files which contains their base64string.

I added them into my DB.

Voice quality decreased a little bit but it worked fine.

Here are my scripts:

amr to mp3: `find . -name "*.amr" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -ar 22050 {}.mp3 \;`

mp3 to txt: `find . -name "*.mp3" -exec bash -c 'for f; do base64 "$f" > "$f.txt"; done' _ {} \;`